# I am trying to run ShowFileStatusTest given in hadoop definited guide book, I get the following error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.836 sec <<< FAILURE!
throwsFileNotFoundForNonExistentFile(org.anahata.play.hadoop.ShowFileStatusTest)  Time elapsed: 3.667 sec  <<< ERROR!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.startDataNodes(MiniDFSCluster.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:280)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:124)
at org.anahata.play.hadoop.ShowFileStatusTest.setUp(ShowFileStatusTest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

fileStatusForFile(org.anahata.play.hadoop.ShowFileStatusTest)  Time elapsed: 0.072 sec  <<< ERROR!

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /tmp/dfs/name1. The directory is already locked.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:602)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1219)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:124)
at org.anahata.play.hadoop.ShowFileStatusTest.setUp(ShowFileStatusTest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

fileStatusForDirectory(org.anahata.play.hadoop.ShowFileStatusTest)  Time elapsed: 0.044 sec  <<< ERROR!

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot lock storage /tmp/dfs/name1. The directory is already locked.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:602)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1219)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:124)
at org.anahata.play.hadoop.ShowFileStatusTest.setUp(ShowFileStatusTest.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

Comment: This example is given on Page 64 of the book.

Comment: Do you have another instance of a Namenode running on this machine (i.e. a pseudo or clustered instance)

Comment: @ChrisWhite: no, no other namenode instance is running.

Comment: Does the directory `/tmp/dfs/name1` exist, does the current user have permissions to write to this folder, and is there a file named `in_use.lock` present in that folder?

Comment: if so what does `fuser /tmp/dfs/name1/in_use.lock` show?

Comment: Chris: there is no in_use.lock file in the folder /tmp/dfs/name1. Don't know about the permissions, please see the full log here. http://pastebin.com/cWSdMZqw

thanks for the interest.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11102/discussion-between-chris-white-and-apurv)

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in our chat session, this is a problem in the `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(String[], Configuration, SecureResources)` method, which asserts that the data node data directories must be `rwxr-xr-x`.

There is a warning in the logs saying that you current have them as 'rwxr-x-r-x'. You'll need to configure your sessions umask (a linux concept, not a java 'thing') to be 0022, rather than the current value of 0002. Execute `umask` in the terminal to confirm this, then set it with `umask 0022`. Now your tests should succeed.

Depending on how you're executing your tests, you may need to apply the umask to your bash profile, and re-apply it:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: hello Chris, 
Thanks for your reply, I still couldn't get it working, after setting the umask the mvn test hangs in between with the following log.
http://pastebin.com/t6NTLj5t